# Is it safe to git fetch in Jenkins job if the source code checked out already?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

In all of our Jenkins jobs we delete the files in the workspace before checking out the code:

```
        steps {
            // Clean workspace before doing anything
            deleteDir()

            checkout scm
        }
```

But when looking at the pods created for build jobs I can see that there are many different folders under `workspace` directory containing the previously checked out the code.

Given each workspace directory is unique and is created for each `git` branch, I believe it is safe to check if the source code is already there at build time, instead of deleting files and checking out the code we can perhaps use `git fetch` instead.

Is my assumption correct and can it be reliable? I am trying to reduce the build time as checking out the code is taking from 1 to 8 minutes depending on the size of the repository.

I once removed `deleteDir()` but the jobs were failing because of some issues with `.git` files.

We are using groovy code and we have our own build library, so things like checking out the code and or maven builds are done manually and not through `Jenkins Pipeline`.

Answer (score 0):

You assumption is correct and it saves lot of time if you have frequent builds. But we found out that some times it is not getting the latest code from github. So it is nice to have a checkbox for a clean build which delete the workspace and clone the repo.

Comment: Well that's a big issue then. Our development environment constantly gets lots of code change and if just one fails, a series of email flows asking for help! I don't want that to happen really. I found a lot of strange behaviour in Jenkins that don't make sense... that's why I ask this question to know about other's experiences. Thanks for sharing